# New tag for Clear Linux

Tags: feature-request, tags

There are tags for distro-specific questions like

- [arch-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arch-linux), [manjaro](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manjaro), [mandriva](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mandriva)
- [linux-mint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint), - [debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debian), [ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu), [lubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lubuntu), [xubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xubuntu), [kubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kubuntu), [chrubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrubuntu), [ubuntu-mate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-mate), [elementary-os](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-os), [kali-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux)
- [fedora](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fedora), [oracle-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-linux), [centos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/centos)
- [scientific-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-linux), [alpine-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpine-linux), [puppy-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puppy-linux), [void-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/void-linux), [tails-os](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tails-os), [solus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solus)...

But none is available for [Clear Linux](https://distrowatch.com/clear) although it was available for years and there are already several questions about it

- [How to install a specific version of a ClearLinux bundle?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/395858/44425)
- [How to install something in ClearLinux without a bundle?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/395840/44425)
- [Clear Linux desktop doesn't start in a virtual machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/450302/44425)
- [Booting clear linux live image on usb from old non-eufi/efi computer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/401255/44425)
- [Can't create a bootable USB/DVD for Clear linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/425135/44425)
- ...

Comment: based on https://clearlinux.org/documentation/clear-linux/concepts/swupd-about#reference, it seems sufficiently unique to warrant its own audience in my opinion.

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes, because Intel made the distro from scratch without basing on any other distros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: [clear-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clear-linux).

Comment: Add a tag wiki or excerpt too!

Comment: @muru It's self-explanatory.

Comment: to you and me, maybe. Probably not to a random new user who starts typing clear in the tag box because they want to clear something related to Linux.

Comment: @muru Waiting for review.